# removeFooterView is not removing footer view

Tags: android, android-listview

Here is the chunk of  my code

```
if (!allFilesAreFolders || itemsInCurrentFolder.length == 0 ) 
            lv.addFooterView(v);
        else lv.removeFooterView(v);

        fileList = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity(), item, path);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
```

My footer is successfully added when needed but nothing happens after the `lv.removeFooterView(v);` - the footer is still there.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the visibility of your view to GONE or INVISIBLE?  possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764238/problem-removing-listview-footer-using-removefooterview

Comment: 1) Do you get any error trace?

Comment: 2) Is removeFooterView() actually called?

Comment: Yes it is called, checked few times in a debugger mode

Comment: I guess you are in a `ListActivity`. But what is `lv`?

Comment: I am in a ListFragment and ListView lv = this.getListView();

Comment: Maybe you should provide more code..otherwise I can't think of any solution

Comment: Too bad. Anyway, thanks for your effort xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically it is sum of two parts:

1. Using View.setVisibility() - as recommended by [forgivegod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794088/forgivegod)
2. Not deleting footer but rather checking if there is one using `ListView.getFooterViewsCount()`

Comment: set the view to gone and the view will no longer occupy screen real estate. Good answer!